# Finding pipe and redirects in perl @ARGV

Tags: perl, pipe, argv, diamond-operator

When writing a traditional Unix/Linux program perl provides the diamond operator <>.  I'm trying to understand how to test if there are no argument passed at all to avoid the perl script sitting in a wait loop for STDIN when it should not.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Reading @ARGV when pipe or redirect on the command line
use warnings;
use strict;

while ( defined (my $line = <ARGV>)) { 
    print "$ARGV: $. $line" if ($line =~ /eof/) ;  # an example
    close(ARGV) if eof;
}

sub usage {
    print  << "END_USAGE" ;
    Usage:
        $0 file
        $0 < file
        cat file | $0    
END_USAGE
    exit();
}
```

A few outputs runs shows that the <> works, but with no arguments we are hold in wait for STDIN input, which is not what I want.

```
$ cat grab.pl | ./grab.pl
-: 7     print "$ARGV: $. $line" if ($line =~ /eof/) ;  # an example
-: 8     close(ARGV) if eof;

$ ./grab.pl < grab.pl
-: 7     print "$ARGV: $. $line" if ($line =~ /eof/) ;  # an example
-: 8     close(ARGV) if eof;

$ ./grab.pl grab.pl
grab.pl: 7     print "$ARGV: $. $line" if ($line =~ /eof/) ;  # an example
grab.pl: 8     close(ARGV) if eof;

$ ./grab.pl
^C
$ ./grab.pl
[Ctrl-D]
$
```

First thought is to test $#ARGV which holds the number of the last argument in @ARGV. Then I added a test to above script, before the while loop like so:

```
if ( $#ARGV < 0 ) {   # initiated to -1 by perl
    usage();
}
```

This did not produced the desired results. $#ARGV is -1 for the redirect and pipe on the command line. Running with this check (grabchk.pl) the problem changed and I can't read the file content by the <> in the pipe or redirect cases.

```
$ ./grabchk.pl grab.pl
grab.pl: 7     print "$ARGV: $. $line" if ($line =~ /eof/) ;
grab.pl: 8     close(ARGV) if eof;

$ ./grabchk.pl < grab.pl
    Usage:
        ./grabchk.pl file
        ./grabchk.pl < file
        cat file | ./grabchk.pl

$ cat grab.pl | ./grabchk.pl
    Usage:
        ./grabchk.pl file
        ./grabchk.pl < file
        cat file | ./grabchk.pl
```

Is there a better test to find all the command line parameters passed to perl by the shell?

Comment: This is an aside, but never write `if ($#array < 0)` when you can write `if (@array == 0)` or `unless (@array)`. Using "the last index in the array" when you want "the number of elements in the array" is not saying what you mean.

Comment: I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [file test operator -t](http://www.bestofperl.com/2011/05/file-test-operators/) to check if the file handle STDIN is open to a TTY.

So if it is open to a terminal and there are no arguments then you display the usage text.

```
if ( -t STDIN and not @ARGV ) {
    # print usage and exit
}
```

Comment: Thanks for test, any ideas how to access the shell command line

Comment: You are welcome. I don't think you can access the command line apart from reading arguments from @ARGV.

Comment: Your Perl program, when looking at its arguments, doesn't see anything before the pipe or after the redirect operator.  The shell parses them and connects them to file descriptors for your program to access.  See [this Perlmonks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=523472) on how your program can determine what those file descriptors are connected to.  Long story short: it's platform-dependent, and your best bet might be using the `lsof` program.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it, since as a side effect using <> in pipe and redirects is that the diamond operators replaces the file name ($ARGV) with '-' if @ARGV is empty, and to know actual file name can be important depending on script purpose.

Comment: @Debinix, Why do you want the command line? Why do think there even was a bash command line involved in launching your program? What value do you think there is to know it the command line if there was one?

Comment: @ikegami, This was an initial thought for the test. With access to the the full command line arguments that could help to solve my problem. Maybe you are right, that would not help anyway, i.e. would I really get access to the symbols '<' and pipe '|'? Also it's hard to find the actual file names in this situation, but that question is a new topic.

Answer (score 0):

use -t operator to check if STDIN is connected to a tty
when you use pipe or shell redirection, it will return false, so you use

```
if ( -t STDIN and not @ARGV ){ exit Usage(); }
```

Comment: -1: this just repeats part of the earlier answer by Oleg Pavliv.